# Problems with merge_asof in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I m trying to merge two pandas on users and closest datetime (forward). My code is this:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values([ 'user_id', 'withdrawal_request_date']).reset_index(drop = True)
deposits = deposits.sort_values(['user_id', 'deposit_date']).reset_index(drop = True)

d_merged = pd.merge_asof(deposits, df1, left_on='deposit_date', right_on = 'withdrawal_request_date', by='user_id', direction='forward')
```

However, I keep geting this error:

> ValueError: left keys must be sorted

I have tried removing the timezone but still same error. Also, as you can see I tried reseting the index but still nothing.

Comment: Sorting by userid is not required as that will be used by the exact join. Just sort the df by left join and right join columns i.e. withdrawal_request_date & deposit_date.

Comment: Replace `.sort_values(['user_id', '**_date'])` by `.sort_values('**_date')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by userid is not required as that will be used by the exact join. Just sort the df by left join and right join columns i.e. withdrawal_request_date & deposit_date.

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['withdrawal_request_date'])
deposits = deposits.sort_values(['deposit_date'])
```